# Creating a Pie Chart in a Razor View in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, charts

I've been searching the whole internet for a guide to help me get a chart working on a Razor Page View from my Asp Net Core project. The thing is, so far I've found stuff using Angular or sites offering a .js for a certain price. Until I stumbled upon a tutorial and put together a code, only to find out that

> The type or namespace Chart could not be found

The code looks like this:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public DashboardController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Total_Releases, Completed_Releases FROM ReleaseStats":
        string constr = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        List<ReleaseStatistics> chartData = new List<ReleaseStatistics>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new ReleaseStatistics
                        {
                            TotalReleases = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Total_Releases"]),
                            CompletedReleases = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Completed_Releases"])
                        });
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return View(chartData);
    }
}
```

---

```
@model List<Intersection.Models.Statistics.ReleaseStatistics>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @{
        var chart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 500, theme: ChartTheme.Yellow)
       .AddTitle("Releases")
       .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: Model, xField: "Total Releases",
            yValues: Model, yFields: "Completed Releases")
        .Write();
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore - What should be done so that my View will be able to see the `Chart()` method? Is there any other way that I could easily add a chart to my view? Any links to guides, tutorials, are very welcome! Although I feel that I already consumed them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chart helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.chart?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) supports asp.net but does not support asp.net core.

If you want to create a pie chart in asp.net core.I suggest that you could try to use [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Reference:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-charts-with-asp-net-core/